# Как правильно импортировать массив в компонент?

Tags: vue.js

Есть  text.js массивом.

```
export default 
 [
    'some text',
    'some  text1',
    'some text2'
]
```

Импортирую его в родительский компонент App.vue

```
import article from '@/components/Text.js'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
      text: {
        article
      }
    }
  }
```

Пытаюсь вывести нужный текст с указание индекса

```
{{text[0]}}
```

Но не работает
если не указывать индекс то выводит просто весь массив

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал делать импорт через переменную для массива, не работает.
Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы делаете так:

```
text: {
        article
      }
```

То вы автоматически создаете свойство `article` у `text` объекте.
Вам нужно использовать в шаблоне

```
{{text.article[0]}}
```

или

```
text: article
```

в шаблоне

```
{{text[0]}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ответ в правильно экспорте

```
let article =
 [
    'some text',
    'some  text1',
    'some text2'
];

export {article};
```